# Labeling boxplots in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I need to build a boxplot without any axes and add it to the current plot (ROC curve), but I need to add more text information to the boxplot: the labels for min and max. Current line of code is below (current graph also).

Thanks a lot for assistance.

```
boxplot(data, horizontal = TRUE, range = 0, axes=FALSE, col = "grey", add = TRUE)
```

The other solution is add the line from 0 to 1 (instead of x-axis), but I want it to go through the central line...for example like this graphic

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I think you will find this produces something like your hand-drawn diagram.

```
data    <- c(0.4, 0.7, 0.75, 0.82, 0.9)
endaxis <- c(0, 1)  # endpoints of axis
datamm  <- c(min(data), max(data))
boxplot(data, horizontal = TRUE, range = 0, ylim = endaxis,
                    axes = FALSE, col = "grey", add = FALSE)
arrows(endaxis, 1,  datamm, 1,  code = 1, angle = 90, length = 0.1)
valuelabels <- c(endaxis[1], round(fivenum(data)[2], digits = 2) ,
                 round(fivenum(data)[4], digits = 2), endaxis[2]  ) 
text(x = valuelabels, y = c(1.05, 1.25, 1.25, 1.05), labels = valuelabels)
```

[image: R boxplot with value labels]

There are probably better ways of doing it.
You may need to adapt it to fit your ROC plot, including changing `add = FALSE`

Comment: Well, your response seems more close to what was asked by the OP (so I've +1). However, I feel like this isn't a boxplot anymore, or at least it loose its interest in spotting possible outlying value. Of note, you can customize a little bit more the boxplot (see the `pars` arguments to reduce its aspect ratio (`boxwex`) and the size of the whiskers (`staplewex`)).

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this for a standalone version:

```
bxp <- boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE)
mtext(c("Min","Max"), side=3, at=bxp$stats[c(1,5)], line=-3)
```

Note that you can get some information when calling `boxplot`, in particular the "five numbers".

If you want it to be superimposed onto another graphic, use `add=T` but replace `mtext` by `text`; you will need to set a $y$ value (which depend on the way you plot the other graphic).

A more complete example was given by [John Maindonald](http://maths.anu.edu.au/~johnm/) (code should be on his website):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fully customizable [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) boxplot...

```
#bootstrap
data <- data.frame(value=rnorm(100,mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2),group=0)
#processing
metaData <- ddply(data,~group,summarise,
            mean=mean(data$value),
   sd=sd(data$value),
            min=min(data$value),
   max=max(data$value),
            median=median(data$value),
   Q1=0,Q3=0
   )
bps <- boxplot.stats(data$value,coef=1.5) 
metaData$min <- bps$stats[1] #lower wisker
metaData$max <- bps$stats[5] #upper wisker
metaData$Q1 <- bps$stats[2] # 1st Quartile
metaData$Q3 <- bps$stats[4] # 3rd Quartile

#adding outliers
out <- data.frame() #initialising storage for outliers
if(length(bps$out) > 0){
 for(n in 1:length(bps$out)){
  pt <-data.frame(value=bps$out[n],group=0) 
  out<-rbind(out,pt) 
 }
}
#adding labels
labels <-data.frame(value=metaData$max, label="Upper bound")
labels <-rbind(labels,data.frame(value=metaData$min, label="Lower bound"))
labels <-rbind(labels,data.frame(value=metaData$median, label="Median"))
labels <-rbind(labels,data.frame(value=metaData$Q1, label="First quartile"))
labels <-rbind(labels,data.frame(value=metaData$Q3, label="Third quartile"))

#drawing
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(metaData,aes(x=group,y=mean))
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=c(0.1,0,0.1),y=c(0,0,1),xend=c(0,0,-0.1),yend=c(0,1,1)))
p <- p + geom_text(aes(y=c(0,1),label=c(0,1),x=0.2))
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype = 1,width = 0.5) #main range
p <- p + geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype = 1,width = 0, color="white")# white line range
p <- p + geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype = 2)    #main range dotted
p <- p + geom_crossbar(aes(y=median,,ymin=Q1,ymax=Q3),linetype = 1,fill='white') #box
if(length(out) >0) p <- p + geom_point(data=out,aes(x=group,y=value),shape=4) # drawning outliers if any
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(0))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(name= "Value")
p <- p + geom_text(data=labels,aes(x=0.5,y=value,label=round(value,2)),colour="black",angle=0,hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5,size=3)

p <- p + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white",colour = NA)) 
p <- p + opts(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), panel.grid.major = theme_blank())
p <- p + opts(axis.title.x=theme_blank())
p <- p + opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank())
p <- p + opts(axis.title.y=theme_blank())
p <- p + opts(axis.text.y = theme_blank())

p + coord_flip()
```

Result:

[image]

...code maybe a bit ugly but works the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is mine implementation of your solutions. I've decided not to map the mean value, there is not to much space left. Also the line from 0 to 1 seems odd.
Thank's a lot everyone.

```
data <- read.table("roc_average.txt")
bxp <- boxplot(data, horizontal = TRUE, range = 0, axes = FALSE, col = "grey", add = TRUE, at = 0.2, varwidth=FALSE, boxwex=0.3)
valuelabels <- c(round(fivenum(data)[2], digits = 2), round(fivenum(data)[4], digits = 2))
text(x = valuelabels, y = c(0.35, 0.35), labels = valuelabels, font = 2)
mtext(c(min(round(data, digits = 2)),max(round(data, digits = 2))), side=1, at=bxp$stats[c(1,5)], line=-3, font = 2)
```

[image: roc curve with boxplot]

Comment: The boxplot is supposed to summarize the AUC? If so, why is the min value = 0.5?

Comment: yep, seems strange, because several ROC should be below 0.5. Digging up what's wrong...

Comment: That is the point I have inverted the ROC AUC for values below 0.5, so the graphics should be remade. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for coming back, I'm waiting for your update. If you're working with different classifiers, you might have a look at [ROCR](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/).

Comment: I did ROC curve with ROCR